# Program throwing target invocation error?

Tags: c#, .net, file

Here is a code which I have written

```
    if(Condition)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path) ; 
        }
        catch ( Win32Exception Error)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(Error.Message)  ;
        }
    }
```

Now, when I provided invalid input to

```
    Path
```

ie a file that does not exist, instead of throwing the Win32 exception,  my application is throwing

```
    TargetInvocationError
```

How can I correct this ?   ![enter image description here][1]
Here is the stack trace

[image]

I then tried adding the lines

```
    catch(FileNotFoundException Error)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(Error.Message) ; 
    }
```

but still the `TargetInvocationException` is being thrown.

Comment: you had better try finding why the exception is throw, resolve it and adding a try-catch is the last attempt to prevent your application from being crashed by some hidden runtime exception.

Answer (score 1):

Either you catch the `TargetInvocationException` or you catch an exception higher up in the hierarchy, like the base class `Exception`.

Like this:

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path) ; 
}
catch ( Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)  ;
}
```

The other options is to catch both

```
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Path) ; 
}
catch ( TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)  ;
}
catch ( Win32Exception ex ) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)  ;
}
```

However, "programming with exceptions" is not recommended (that is, using exceptions as part of your application flow). Instead make sure that `Path` is valid before you try to use it. Providing an informative message that the path is incorrect instead of giving your users some cryptic message.

Comment: But when the `TargetInvocationException` is thrown the debugger points to the statement  `Application.Run(new FormClass()) ;`

Comment: I have made sure all this but still the exception is occurring . I am posting the stack trace, please check it.

Comment: And I guess the code in your question is somewhere in `FormClass`? Unhandled exceptions are thrown upwards the stack and the line in your comment probably is the last stack frame you have code for, hence the unhandled exception will blow up there. Please read more on exception handling here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

Comment: I don't think that the problem lies there. I tried modifying the `Win32Exception` to `Exception` but of no use, the exception still occurs at `Application.Run(new FormClass()) ;`